# Removed from a TypedArray

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Object in type TypedArray. Is there the possibility to remove objects from there? Here is my code where Deck is in type TypedArray. I'm trying to remove the integer randomIntD

```
public void onClick(View view){
    int randomIntD = random2.nextInt(Deck.length());
    int drawableIDD = Deck.getResourceId(randomIntD, -1);    
    //Deck.remove(randomIntD);
    backgroundD2.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDD);
}
```

Comment: You want to remove objects from a predefined array?  I think you mean to use an arrayList so that you can use functions like .remove() and .add()

Comment: That's not my part of the code. We are worked in group. Do you suggest to change it in arrayList. Are there some big differences?

Comment: Once an array is created you cannot change the size of it.  You can replace values, set values to null, overrite values etc. but the size of the array will remain constant.  You can copy the values you want into a new array, or you can choose to use an arrayList.  An arraylist allows you to add and remove values dynamically.